# URL request returns empty array (JSON, PHP)

Tags: php, json, url, request

I'm trying to fetch some data. I'm new to this PHP thing, JSON as well. When I print, it just gives me an empty array. Since I don't get any errors, I suppose everything else is fine.

```
  $request = new WP_Http;
  $result = $request->request($url, $data = array());
  $input = json_encode($request, true);
  print($input);
```

Comment: Try `print_r` or `var_dump` instead of `print`

Comment: Have you printed out `$result` to see what it looks like yet?

Comment: `print` gives me {}, `print_r` gives me Array{}, `var_dump` gives me string(2)"{}"... I don't understand what `var_dump` is trying to tell me?

Comment: I have printed `$result`... it gives me something like this (shortened): `Array ( [headers] => Array ( [server] => ZGS [date] => Wed, 12 Aug 2015 11:02:02 GMT [content-type] => text/xml;charset=utf-8 [connection] => close [set-cookie] => Array ( [0] => 2803525351=f4606535ba1c0facda8910343cc9b6d3; Path=/ [1] => JSESSIONID=6439C6713D9D9435FB1DDE14065446E6;`

Answer (score 3):

You have to call

```
$input = json_encode($result, true);
```

instead of

```
$input = json_encode($request, true);
```

Comment: Thanks! It got me closer, and I can now see the data, but the way it spits it out is quite ugly. How can I solve this?

Comment: How does the json-encoded data look like? Please post it ;-)

Comment: [CDATA[23 Apr-2015]]\u003E\u003C\/FL\u003E\u003CFL val=\"Oprettet af\"\u003E\u003C![CDATA[(employee name)(092)]]\u003E\u003C\/FL\u003E\u003C\/row\u003E\u003Crow no=\"3\"\u003E\u003CFL val=\"JOBOPENINGID\"\u003E\u003C!

Comment: I understand an issue is that there are æøå characters in the data and fields. I tried `utf8_encode` but no luck